# How do I upgrade my booth?

Tags: papers-please

The game says there's a booth upgrade available, and to press space to toggle inspection mode. I don't know where I should do that, though. Tried during the game and pressing space there apparently does nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to first pay for the upgrade at the "end of the day" screen.

Comment: To be clear, "end of the day" screen has payments listed and each item has a circle (button) near them enabling you to activate that option like "upgrade booth". Learned it the hard way after all my family members died.